# Почему не запускается код?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

```
import subprocess

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(959, 365)
        Form.setStyleSheet("")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(Form)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 230, 421, 41))
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(23, 30, 441, 41))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font: 87 12pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(494, 20, 421, 61))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("font: 87 12pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 421, 41))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 80, 431, 41))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(25, 164, 421, 21))
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("font: 87 12pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(493, 160, 421, 31))
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("font: 87 12pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(21, 190, 421, 41))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(489, 190, 431, 41))
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 280, 901, 51))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("font: 87 26pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("Form", "Использовать тот же путь"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Введи путь до исходного файла"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Введи название исходного файла"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "Введи путь до конечного файла"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Form", "Введи название конечного файла"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Конвертировать"))

class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        file = self.lineEdit.Text() + "/" + self.lineEdit_2
        x = self.checkBox.isChecked()
```

должен открыться интерфейс, а он не открывается, что делать?

Comment: у вас несколько опечаток. Замените `file = self.lineEdit.Text() + "/" + self.lineEdit_2`  на `file = self.lineEdit.text() + "/" + self.lineEdit_2.text()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не должен, т.к. вы не создали `QApplication` и не создали окно-виджет:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
...

app = QApplication([])

mw = Main()
mw.show()

app.exec()
```

---

`QApplication` нужен для работы оконных приложений, а сами окна (виджеты) не появятся пока вы не создадите их объекты и не сделаете их видимыми